# Limit fields of a find operator using java monogodb

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of users with an embedded document array containing the id of his friends.

```
{
  "_id": "11",
  "name": "jhon",
  "userFriends": [
    {
      "user_id": "22"
    },
    {
      "user_id": "12"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get all friends ID where `_id` = "11";

I am trying to use this using java code

```
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject().append("userFriends.user_id", 1); 
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject().append("_id", "1"); 
DBCursor results = coll.find(query, fields);
```

But I am getting this error:

> method find(Bson, Class) in the type MongoCollection is not applicable for the arguments (BasicDBObject, BasicDBObject):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying a newer version of MongoDB(3.0+) and writing code in the older style. For 2.13 version or for 3.0 (with some deprecated methods), this works fine.

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(
            "localhost", 27017));
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = (DB) mongo.getDB("testDB");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("coll");
    BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject().append(
            "userFriends.user_id", 1).append("_id", 0);
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject().append("_id", "11");
    DBObject dbObj = collection.findOne(query, fields);
    BasicDBList list = (BasicDBList) dbObj.get("userFriends");

    String[] arr = new String[list.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        DBObject obj = (DBObject) list.get(i);
        arr[i] = (String) obj.get("user_id");
    }
```

In newer style,

```
    import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(
            "localhost", 27017));
    MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("testDB");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("coll");
    Document doc = collection.find(eq("_id", "11")).projection(Projections.include("userFriends.user_id")).first();

    List list = (List) doc.get("userFriends");
    String[] arr = new String[list.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Document obj = (Document) list.get(i);
        arr[i] = (String) obj.get("user_id");
    }
```

For more details of using 3.0 with Java refer [Quick Tour](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/).

Comment: how can we take all the friends user_id of a  user and save them in an array of string???